# React screen size if condition returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the following code to check screen size, if smaller than `545px` then x,y,r values changes.
Else they remain the same.

```
const screenWidth = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
if(screenWidth == "545"){
    let x = "200";
    let y = "250";
    let r = "150";
}
else{
    let x = "250";
    let y = "300";
    let r = "250";
}
```

I have debugged screenWidth, it works fine, but I receive compiling error, that x,y,r undefined.

Why I get undefined values when I trying to use if condition to screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const screenWidth = React.useState(window.innerWidth);
 let x=0;
 let y=0;
 let r=0;
if(screenWidth == "545"){
 x = "200";
 y = "250";
 r = "150";
}
else{
 x = "250";
 y = "300";
 r = "250";
 }
```

declaring items initially and then assigning based on conditions is a good practice instead of declaring in a block

hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

This is because [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) declares a block-scoped local variable - meaning the variable does not exist outside of the curly braces in which it is declared.

For example:

```js
let x = 1;

{
  let x = 2 //This is an example of variable shadowing, which you should avoid since it can be confusing. I'm just using it here to demonstrate how the let declaration works
  console.log(`Inside the block x = ${x}`);
}

console.log(`Outside the block x = ${x}`);
```

Once the end of a block is reached (the closing curly bracket), all variables declared inside that block will cease to exist.

FYI - `const` works the same way.